# Select everything that have any extra classes different from 2 selectors (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select everything that have any extra class than these selectors `.not-submenu.separator:not('.first-item')`, `.first-item.not-submenu.separator`
how may i apply a wildcard and a `OR`to this situation?

```
<li class="first-item not-submenu separator"></li>
<li class="not-submenu separator"></li>
<li class="not-submenu separator randomclass1"></li>//remove everything that have an extra class and still matches the other selectors
<li class="not-submenu separator randomclass2"></li>
<li class="not-submenu separator randomclass3"></li>
(...)
<li class="not-submenu separator randomclassn"></li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "extra class than these selectors"? Maybe you should show us the HTML elements that you want to select and not select instead.

Comment: something like: "hey you, class that match selectors 1 and 2 and have a misterious extra class"

Comment: this was the best way i found to illustrate

Comment: Well (and 5 others, evidently) think this would be better illustrated with some sample markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the filter method and return true or false to indicate whether to keep the selected element. Something like this:

```
$(".not-submenu.separator").filter(function(index) {
    // 'this' refers to the current element
    // 'index' is fairly useless but I wanted to demonstrate the API
    return ! $(this).hasClass('something-else');
});
```

That should give you a list of element that match your selector that DON'T have the class "something-else." Incidentally, it was hard to figure out what your actual selector was (which elements you were hoping to end up with), so I went with something simple and common to your two examples.